# Merge public repository with private repository

Tags: git, github, automation, fetch, pull-request

I have a private repository generated from a public repository. How can I merge updates of the public repository with the private repository *without removing additional files*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do following steps in your private repo:

```bash
$ git remote add pub-repo <pub-repo-url>
$ git fetch pub-repo
$ git merge pub-repo/master
```

Then you can get the update of pub-repo.

Once the pub-repo has an update again.

You can just:

```
$ git pull pub-repo/master
$ git merge pub-repo/master
```